# crossval in Matlab- Predfun only runs if it has zero arguments?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm trying to use the `crossval` function built into Matlab. I have a Logistic Regression function set up and ready to go, but the behaviour I'm getting is not what I'd expect from the documentation.

From the [Crossval documentation page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html), the overload:

```
mse = crossval('mse',X,y,'Predfun',predfun)
```

seemed to fit what I needed best. The doocumentation says

> mse = crossval('mse',X,y,'Predfun',predfun) returns mse, a scalar
>   containing a 10-fold cross validation estimate of mean-squared error
>   for the function predfun. X can be a column vector, matrix, or array
>   of predictors. y is a column vector of response values. X and y must
>   have the same number of rows.
>
> predfun is a function handle called with the training subset of X, the
>   training subset of y, and the test subset of X as follows:
>
> yfit = predfun(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST)
>
> Each time it is called, predfun should use XTRAIN and ytrain to fit a
>   regression model and then return fitted values in a column vector
>   yfit. Each row of yfit contains the predicted values for the
>   corresponding row of XTEST. crossval computes the squared errors
>   between yfit and the corresponding response test set, and returns the
>   overall mean across all test sets.

So I defined a function in another file in the same directory, with the signature:

```
function ytest = logRegTester(XTRAIN, ytrain, XTEST)
```

Matlab was giving me the error

> Error using logRegTester (line 11)
>   Not enough input arguments.

To experiment, I tried reducing the number of arguments logRegTester expected, and found `crossval` would only call my function if it had zero arguments. Which seems to contradict the documentation, which wants a function with three arguments.

Comment: Is it possible that you don't use a function handle as required, but directly use logRegTester ? To get a function handle use @logRegTester instead (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [function handle](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) @logRegTester as required by predfun() instead using logRegTester directly.